# double free or corruption (!prev) and I cannot figure out why in C

Tags: c, memcpy, memset

I have been sometime struggling with this issue and I cannot find the reason why this leak is happening.

What I pretend is to order eb and db as I order fileblock, so first I order fileblock with its eb and db memory pieces. After this I want to copy this data, stored in the structure, to db, eb and fileblock. So I only want to reorder the data using that in the middle structure.

I paste here the code and after it I explain more in depth the problem and the tests I have carried out:

```
struct reorder_blocks_s
{
  int64_t pos;
  int64_t originalPos;
  int64_t nextPos;
  int64_t newSeekLenPos;
  int64_t ctrl[3];
  uint8_t *dataBlock;
  uint8_t *extraBlock;
};

static void initReorderBlocks ( struct reorder_blocks_s *structure,
                                uint64_t size )
{
  memset(structure, 0, sizeof(struct reorder_blocks_s));
}

static void reorderBlocks (uint8_t *fileblock, uint8_t *db, uint8_t *eb,
                           int64_t ctrllen, int64_t dblen, int64_t eblen,
                           int64_t newsize )
{
 uint32_t count = 0;
 int64_t ctrl[3];
 int64_t ctrl2[3];
 uint8_t *auxFileblock = fileblock;
 uint8_t *auxDb = db;
 uint8_t *auxEb = eb;
 uint8_t buf[8];
 uint16_t problematicCount = 0;
 uint64_t currentPos = 0;
 uint32_t maxToSave = 0;
 bool firstTime = true;


 struct reorder_blocks_s *newFileBlock;
 newFileBlock = malloc ( sizeof(struct reorder_blocks_s) *
                         (ctrllen / 24) + 1 );

 struct reorder_blocks_s *problematicFields;
 problematicFields = malloc ( sizeof(struct reorder_blocks_s) *
                              (ctrllen / 24) + 1 );

 struct reorder_blocks_s * auxProblematicFields;
 int64_t *bytesNeededToSave = malloc(sizeof(int64_t)*(ctrllen / 24));

 struct reorder_blocks_s auxReorderStructure;
 struct reorder_blocks_s auxProblematicStructure;


 /* Init the structures. */
 initReorderBlocks( newFileBlock, ctrllen / 24 );
 initReorderBlocks( &auxReorderStructure, 1 );

 /* First it would be needed to go throght fileblock (ctrlblock) storing all
  * the data in the structure to be arranged.
  */
//  printf("ctrllen, dblen, eblen: %ld, %ld, %ld\n", ctrllen, dblen, eblen);
//
//printf("Imprimo los newFileBlock SIN ORDENAR\n");
//
//printf("Direccion de memoria de db:%ld\n", db);
//printf("Direccion de memoria de eb:%ld\n", eb);
uint32_t dbSUM = 0;
uint32_t ebSUM = 0;
  for (int64_t i = 0; i < ctrllen / 24; i++ )
  {
    ctrl[0] = offtin(fileblock);
       ctrl[1] = offtin(fileblock+8);
       ctrl[2] = offtin(fileblock+16);
    if( ctrl[0] != 0 )
      newFileBlock[i].dataBlock = malloc( sizeof(uint8_t) * ctrl[0] );
    else
      newFileBlock[i].dataBlock = NULL;

    if( ctrl[1] != 0 )
      newFileBlock[i].extraBlock = malloc( sizeof(uint8_t) * ctrl[1] );
    else
      newFileBlock[i].dataBlock = NULL;

    if ( firstTime )
    { 
      newFileBlock[i].originalPos = 0;
      firstTime = false;
    }
    else
      newFileBlock[i].originalPos = currentPos;

    newFileBlock[i].pos = count;

    /* Copy ctrl 24 bytes into the structure field ctrl. */
    memcpy( &(newFileBlock[i].ctrl), ctrl, sizeof(int64_t) * 3);
    if( newFileBlock[i].dataBlock != NULL )
      memcpy( newFileBlock[i].dataBlock, db, sizeof(uint8_t) * ctrl[0]);
    if( newFileBlock[i].extraBlock != NULL )
      memcpy( newFileBlock[i].extraBlock, eb, sizeof(uint8_t) * ctrl[1]);

    if(memcmp(newFileBlock[i].extraBlock, eb, sizeof(uint8_t) * ctrl[1]))
    {
      printf("ERROR GRRRRR\n");
      exit(0);
    }

//    printf("ctrl[0]: %ld\t ctrl[1]: %ld\t ctrl[2]: %ld\t y posicion de memoria \
//            original: %ld\n", newFileBlock[i].ctrl[0], newFileBlock[i].ctrl[1]
//            , newFileBlock[i].ctrl[2], newFileBlock[i].originalPos );

    db         += ctrl[0];
    eb         += ctrl[1];
    currentPos += ctrl[0] + ctrl[2];
    fileblock  += 24;
    count++;
    dbSUM += ctrl[0];
    ebSUM += ctrl[1];
  }

  /* fileblock pointer pointing to the memory initial address of ctrl block. */
  fileblock = auxFileblock;

  /* Restore db and eb pointers to their initial addresses. */
//  printf("ANTES DE RESTORE. Direccion de memoria de db: %ld\n", db);
//  printf("ANTES DE RESTORE. Direccion de memoria de eb: %ld\n", eb);
  db = auxDb;
  eb = auxEb;
//  printf("Direccion de memoria de db :%ld\n", db);
//  printf("Direccion de memoria de eb: %ld\n", eb);
//  printf("dbSUM: %ld\n", dbSUM);
//  printf("ebSUM: %ld\n", ebSUM);


  /* Once the data has been stored its is time to order all the structure,
   * modifiying from the lower address to the higher one.
   */
  for (int64_t i = 0; i < ctrllen / 24; ++i)
  {
    for (int64_t j = i + 1; j < ctrllen / 24; ++j)
    {
      if ((newFileBlock[i].originalPos > newFileBlock[j].originalPos))
      {
        memcpy( &auxReorderStructure, &newFileBlock[i], sizeof(struct reorder_blocks_s));
        memcpy( &newFileBlock[i], &newFileBlock[j], sizeof(struct reorder_blocks_s));
        memcpy( &newFileBlock[j], &auxReorderStructure, sizeof(struct reorder_blocks_s));
      }
    }
  }


  /* Clean the data block and the extra block is recommended before setting
   * them again.FAILING IF I USE IT!!!!
   */
   //why are those memsets affecting the code!!!
//  memset(db, 0x00, newsize + 1);
//  memset(eb, 0x00, newsize + 1);
//  for ( int64_t i = 0; i < dblen + 1; i++ )
//  {
//    *db = 0x00;
//    db += 1;
//  }
//  
//   for ( int64_t i = 0; i < eblen + 1; i++ )
//  {
//    *eb = 0x00;
//    eb += 1;
//  }
//  db = auxDb;
//  eb = auxEb;

//  uint32_t dbcounter = 0;
//  uint32_t ebcounter = 0;
  /* Regenerate db block and eb block. */
  for ( int64_t i = 0; i < ctrllen / 24; i++ )
  {
   /* Copy to the newFileBlock structure the reordered data to be modified and
    * the extra data aswell.
    */
    if ( newFileBlock[i].dataBlock != NULL )
    {
    memcpy( db, newFileBlock[i].dataBlock, sizeof(uint8_t) * newFileBlock[i].ctrl[0]);
    db += newFileBlock[i].ctrl[0];
    }
    if ( newFileBlock[i].extraBlock != NULL )
    {
      memcpy( eb, newFileBlock[i].extraBlock, newFileBlock[i].ctrl[1]);
      eb += newFileBlock[i].ctrl[1];
    }
//    dbcounter += newFileBlock[i].ctrl[0];
//    ebcounter += newFileBlock[i].ctrl[1];
//    printf("ctrl[0]: %ld\t ctrl[1]: %ld\t ctrl[2]: %ld\t y posicion de memoria \
//            original: %ld\n", newFileBlock[i].ctrl[0], newFileBlock[i].ctrl[1]
//            , newFileBlock[i].ctrl[2], newFileBlock[i].originalPos );
  }

  for( int64_t i = 0; i < ctrllen / 24; i++)
  {
    if ( newFileBlock[i].dataBlock != NULL )
    {
      free(newFileBlock[i].dataBlock);
    }
    if ( newFileBlock[i].extraBlock != NULL )
    {
      free(newFileBlock[i].extraBlock);
    }
  }

  free(newFileBlock);
  free(problematicFields);
  free(bytesNeededToSave);
  auxDb = NULL;
  auxEb = NULL;
}

int myFunctionToBeUsed( uint8_t* oldp,  const int64_t oldsize, uint8_t* newp,
            const int64_t newsize, uint8_t* patch, const int64_t patchsz )
{
  int64_t dblen,eblen;
  int64_t ctrllen;
  uint8_t *db,*eb;
  uint8_t *fileblock;

  /* Here a lot of complex operations took place in order to calculate db, eb and fileblock. It has been extracted from bsdiff code so it is already tested. */



  /* PREVIOS DATA HAS BEEN FILLED USING SOME COMPLEX FUNCTIONS TO CALCULATE DIFFERENCES BETWEEN 2 BINARIES. IF I DON'T CALL TO REORDERBLOCKS IT WORKS */

  /*UNTIL HERE EVERYTHING SEEMS TO BE WORKING.*/

  reorderBlocks( fileblock, db, eb, ctrllen, dblen, eblen, newsize );

  /* The leak comes up as I free those and with a big file ( 1MB), with smaller ones it works well. */
  free(db);
  free(eb);



  free(fileblock);
}
```

I have checked that I am getting the same eb and db initial addressed inside the function and that I copy to memory the appropriate number of bytes (the original diffprogram doesn't reorder and it works, I just reorder eb and db in the same way I have modified fileblock order). I cannot either memset db and eb, I tried this without reordering, so just copying to the struct and again to eb and db, and I used memcmp to compare the results getting memcmp results differents to ZERO, and as I didn't do any modification the result should be ZERO.

I tried to explain my problem the best I could.

Any advice or help will be really welcome.

**EDITED 05/10/16:**
I have cut down the size of the code a bit. As I was advised I am going to use **valgrind** and paste the results.

valgrind give me this report, but I don't know how can I fix the problems, I have read the Valgrind's documentation. This what I get if I use gcc -static -g *.c -o myprogram:

```
valgrind --track-origins=yes ./minibsdiff gen ivanTestBin/setup1.exe ivanTestBin/setup2.exe ivanTestBin/setuppatch
==5460== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5460== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5460== Using Valgrind-3.12.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5460== Command: ./minibsdiff gen ivanTestBin/setup1.exe ivanTestBin/setup2.exe ivanTestBin/setuppatch
==5460==
==5460== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5460==    at 0x4167F8: _int_free (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x460808: fillin_rpath (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x460E04: _dl_init_paths (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x43C0E3: _dl_non_dynamic_init (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x43C9B7: __libc_init_first (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x4059E4: (below main) (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==  Uninitialised value was created
==5460==    at 0x45DF09: brk (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x43A1D8: sbrk (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x406106: __libc_setup_tls (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x40599C: (below main) (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==
==5460== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5460==    at 0x41684D: _int_free (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x460808: fillin_rpath (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x460E04: _dl_init_paths (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x43C0E3: _dl_non_dynamic_init (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x43C9B7: __libc_init_first (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x4059E4: (below main) (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==  Uninitialised value was created
==5460==    at 0x45DF09: brk (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x43A1D8: sbrk (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x406106: __libc_setup_tls (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x40599C: (below main) (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==
==5460== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5460==    at 0x416248: malloc_consolidate (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x417D36: _int_malloc (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x419D20: malloc (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x45884F: _IO_file_doallocate (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x413A93: _IO_doallocbuf (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x412C97: _IO_file_overflow (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x4120A3: _IO_file_xsputn (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x44AA63: vfprintf (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x40C445: printf (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x4054C3: diff (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x4057CA: main (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==  Uninitialised value was created
==5460==    at 0x45DF09: brk (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x43A1D8: sbrk (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x406106: __libc_setup_tls (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==    by 0x40599C: (below main) (in /home/ivan/ota/binary_diff_tools/bsdiff-master/minibsdiff-master/minibsdiff)
==5460==
Generating binary patch between ivanTestBin/setup1.exe and ivanTestBin/setup2.exe
Old file = 967168 bytes
New file = 965632 bytes
Computing binary delta...
sizeof(delta('ivanTestBin/setup1.exe', 'ivanTestBin/setup2.exe')) = 39922 bytes
Successfully created patch; patch file name: ivanTestBin/setuppatch
==5460==
==5460== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5460==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5460==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==5460==
==5460== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==5460==
==5460== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5460== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

If I don't use static while compiling the result is worrying:

[Valgrind](http://pastebin.com/9F5PJMKy)

**EDITED 06/10/16:**

Well, I solved this. The problem was i wasn't adding the right amount to the db and eb pointing address in the for in which I loaded the content of newFileBlock to db and eb again. I mean, I used ctrl[0] and ctrl[1](http://pastebin.com/9F5PJMKy) and I must use newFileBlock[i].ctrl[0] and newFileBlock[i].ctrl[1](http://pastebin.com/9F5PJMKy). I have already corrected it in the pasted code.

Best regards,

F.

Comment: `memset(&structure, 0, sizeof(structure));` should be `memset(structure, 0, sizeof(*structure) * size);`.

Comment: Can you use [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/)?  If so, do so.  If not, can you reduce the code to an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Eliminate some of the functions; simplify the structures; show us the data that causes the crash.

Comment: @mch That's not a comment. You should submit that as an answer.

Comment: The problems I am getting seem to come from the memset and memcpy, but I don't know what I am doing wrong... I changed many times from just a number to a sizeof(uint8_t) * size in order to indicate the amount of memory to set or copy but I get the same result.

Comment: Strong advice to replace `memset(structure, 0, sizeof(struct reorder_blocks_s));` by `memset(structure, 0, sizeof *structure);` it is shorter and also more robust. Similar for size-arguments for memcpy() and malloc()

Comment: joop. I trust in your advise but I don't understand well that syntax. With *structure I get what the pointer points to, so a struct reorder_blocks_s size, don't I? But why is it more robust?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved this. The problem was i wasn't adding the right amount to the db and eb pointing address in the for in which I loaded the content of newFileBlock to db and eb again. I mean, I used ctrl[0] and ctrl1 and I must use newFileBlock[i].ctrl[0] and newFileBlock[i].ctrl[1]. I have already corrected it in the pasted code.

Best regards.